# Send input information from a dynamic form to another function

Tags: javascript

I do not know how to obtain the information of the generated inputs through a dynamically generated form with javascript.
The idea is that from the form only the information of the inputs is sent to the function.
This is my code:

```
function createForm(formConfig){
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    for (prop in formConfig) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        if (formConfig[prop].type == "text"){
            input.setAttribute('type',"text");
            input.setAttribute('name',formConfig[prop].name);
        }
        else if (formConfig[prop].type == "Number"){
            //
        }

        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    var submit = document.createElement("input");
    submit.setAttribute('type',"button");
    submit.setAttribute('value',"Save");
    submit.setAttribute('onClick',"example(this.form)");
    form.append(submit);
    document.getElementById("formPlace").appendChild(form);
}


function example(form){
    //Function to read the form inputs info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to set the `click` handler instead of using `setAttribute`. And pass in an anonymous function that closes over the `form` variable.

```
submit.addEventListener("click", () => example(form), false);
```

Then in the `example` function loop over the form children and grab the values.